# Date picker localization in material-table(Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, localization, material-ui

Does anyone know how to do localization of date picker in material-table(Material UI)? In this example, date picker is used when filtering.

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

function App() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Simple Action Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Birthday', field: 'birthDay', type: 'date'},
      ]}
      data={[
        { birthDay: "08-30-2020" },
      ]}        
      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The localization of text or the date format? Please be more specific and add some code you have achieved

Comment: The localization of text.

Answer (score 4):

Add the dateSetting in columns.

```js
const columns = [
    {
      title: "Simple Action Preview",
      field: 'birthYear',
      type: "date",
      dateSetting: { locale: "ko-KR"}
      ....
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npx create-react-app datepicker
cd .\datepicker\
npm install material-table @material-ui/core --save
```

File App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import idLocale from 'date-fns/locale/id';

function App() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Simple Action Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Birthday', field: 'birthDay', type: 'date'},
      ]}
      data={[
        { birthDay: "08-30-2020" },
      ]}        
      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
      localization={{
        body: {
          dateTimePickerLocalization: idLocale
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI document of [localization](https://material-ui.com/guides/localization/#locale-text)

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { zhCN } from '@material-ui/core/locale';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: '#1976d2' },
  },
}, zhCN);

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```